# Android - Firebase onChildAdded how to listen for all child

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a problem of displaying the newly added data. My `onChildAdded` is listening for any new notification. This new notification is saved into Firebase. My notification contains 2 child (Message and Date).

However, I'm able only to display one of the child (Date) when I add a new notification. I'm able to retrieve everything if I re-run the app but I want the changes to be made when I'm on the app itself. How can I show everything when I add a new notification? Is it because onChildAdded only listen for the previous child? If needed, I can post my adapter and getter/setter codes.

Example: I sent 2 new notifications and the listener only reads the Date. Screenshot below.

[image]

Not in order. It doesn't display the newly added notification "Message". I added "Hi2" and "Hi3".
[image]

**NotificationFragment.java**

```
public class NotificationFragment extends Fragment {

    private void prepareNotification1() {
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String userID = user.getUid();

//        mRef.child("customers").child(userID).child("Notification").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
//                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
//                    System.out.println(postSnapshot.getValue());
//                    Notification menu = postSnapshot.getValue(Notification.class);
////                    Notification menu = new Notification(postSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
//                    notificationList.add(menu);
//                }
//                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//            }
//
//            @Override
//            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
//
//            }
//
//        });
//


        mRef.child("customers").child(userID).child("Notification").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    Log.d("child", "onChildAdded:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
                    Log.d("child", "onChildAdded:" + dataSnapshot.getValue());
                    Notification menu = dataSnapshot.getValue(Notification.class);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**FirebaseMessaging**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private DatabaseReference mRef;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        final String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        mRef.child("customers").child(userID).child("Notification").child(uniqueID).child("Date").setValue(notificationTime);
        mRef.child("customers").child(userID).child("Notification").child(uniqueID).child("Message").setValue(remoteMessage.getData().get("body"));
        createNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"),remoteMessage.getData().get("body"));
}
```

**Notification.java**

```
public class Notification {
    private String Message;
    private String Date;


    public Notification(){
    }

    public Notification(String Message, String Date){
        this.Message = Message;
        this.Date = Date;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return Date;
    }

    public void setDate(String Date) {
        this.Date = Date;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return Message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String Message) {
        this.Message = Message;
    }
}
```

**NotificationAdapter.java**

```
public class NotificationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotificationAdapter.NotificationHolder> {
    private List<Notification> notificationList;
    private Context mContext;

    public NotificationAdapter(Context mContext, List<Notification> notificationList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.notificationList = notificationList;
    }


    @Override
    public NotificationHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View inflatedView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item_notification, parent, false);
        return new NotificationHolder(inflatedView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final NotificationHolder holder, int position) {
        Notification notification = notificationList.get(position);
        holder.body.setText(notification.getMessage());
        holder.time.setText(notification.getDate());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return notificationList.size();
    }

    public class NotificationHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView body;
        public TextView time;

        public NotificationHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            body = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bodyMsg);
            time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your Notification class code?

Comment: @LucaRossi I've posted all the codes.

Comment: When you get the data in `Notification menu = dataSnapshot.getValue(Notification.class);` the Message field is empty?

Comment: @LucaRossi It's not empty. I'm able to retrieve it when I re-run the app. But, I want is to be able to update it on the 'listView' when I'm on the app instead of closing and launching again. Is it because 'onChildListener' only read the last changes of the child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found the issue, `onChildAdded` gets fired only when a child is  added to the list, so the first time you read them from remote or a new notification is added to the online list.

In this part of code you first add the notification object with only the `Date` field set, then you edit its `Message`

```
mRef.child("customers").child(userID).child("Notification").child(uniqueID).child("Date").setValue(notificationTime);
mRef.child("customers").child(userID).child("Notification").child(uniqueID).child("Message").setValue(remoteMessage.getData().get("body"));
```

That's why when `onChildAdded` is fired you can only see the `Date` field, if you override also the `onChildChanged` you'll see the `Message`

To solve your problem you should add to firebase the whole object like it's explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#basic_write)

This should be the result, following the docs

```
Notification newNotification = new Notification(notificationTime, remoteMessage.getData().get("body"))
mRef.child("customers").child(userID).child("Notification").child(uniqueID).setValue(newNotification);
```

Comment: You can also avoid generating unique keys by yourself, you can use `mRef.child("customers").child(userID).child("Notification").push().getKey();` to get one generated by firebase

Comment: Thanks!! It solved the problem. Yeah, that was the problem but I couldn't explain properly in technical terms. Oh, I was using '.push' but it generated each different key for my "Date" and "Message". I was trying to figure out how to put it in the same key. Thanks for tips and help and ur explanation! I will use that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the case of your property names don't match with the JSON. Specifically: Firebase follows JavaBean conventions, which means that a getter/setter `getName()/setName()` define a property `name` (with a lowercase `n`).

I'd recommend changing your JSON data to match this naming convention. But even with the current JSON you can make things work with a few annotations:

```
public class Notification {
    private String Message;
    private String Date;


    public Notification(){
    }

    public Notification(String Message, String Date){
        this.Message = Message;
        this.Date = Date;
    }

    @PropertyName("Date")
    public String getDate() {
        return Date;
    }

    @PropertyName("Date")
    public void setDate(String Date) {
        this.Date = Date;
    }

    @PropertyName("Message")
    public String getMessage() {
        return Message;
    }

    @PropertyName("Message")
    public void setMessage(String Message) {
        this.Message = Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! But I think the problem wasn't naming convention here. But it's already working.